# how to connect to a server running on computer using computer's IP address?

Tags: node.js, networking, web, browser, ip

I am working on IOT project in which I have to change some variables(fans speed, lights, etc). So just as a starter, I created a node.js server and tried to send requests to the server through a local network using local IP as

> http://localhost:7000/users=mandar?lights=OFF

or

> http://192.168.43.248:7000/users=mandar?lights=OFF

and it works fine.

Now I want to do the same over the internet. So I got Computer's IP address from https://www.google.co.in/search?q=myip and tried to send a request to the following URL:

> http://(IP_address):7000/users=mandar?lights=OFF

This time it keeps on loading and finally shows this site can't be loaded.
So what is the right way to connect to the server through the internet?
Thank you.

Comment: what's you computer IP? And your server IP? if you do a packet capture on the server do you see the request from the computer coming?

Comment: @mr4kino my server is running on the computer on port 7000. Ip address of my computer is 106.193.250.246. I want to send a request to the server using a phone or any other device through internet. And about the request, no request even reaches the server and on phone, the page keeps on loading without any result till it gets timed out.

Comment: Can you run a tcpdump on your server? the command would be the following "tcpdump -nns0X host 106.193.250.246 -w capture.pcap" and attach the .pcap file. You can open it with Wireshark.

Comment: Please do tell reason before down voting. It will be helpful for me in future while asking question. Please Don't down vote without mentioning the reason in comments section. Thanks for feedback.

Comment: @mr4kino I tried it but it didn't work. Thank you for trying to help me ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do port forwarding.

The IP address you get from the google search is the out-facing IP address of your router. However, your router knows your computer by your local IP address (i.e. 192.168.x.y).

You have to configure your router to send packets coming from internet destined to port 7000(or any other port) to your computer's port 7000.

Check your router's documentation on port forwarding. Likely there is a settings page on the web interface of your router that you can do the desired port forwarding. After configuring the router, there are several tools online to test if the port forwarding is actually working. I suggest you use one of those tools to verify the configuration before testing with your project.

You also might want to check if your router has a firewall. You can add an exception to the firewall such that a specific port number is reachable from the internet.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I will try this and let you know :)